# Details of Optional Sampling Theorem Proof

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

I'm looking at the proof of the optional sampling theorem given on p.2-p.3 here http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~conlon/math625/chapter2.pdf.
[image]

I'm a little confused by the equivalence between (2.4) and (2.5).  In particular, I would think we have

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[f(\tilde{X}_1,\cdots,\tilde{X}_n)\tilde{X}_n]&=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[f(X_{k_1},\cdots,X_{k_n})X_{k_n}|m_1=k_1,\cdots,m_n=k_n]]\\
&=\sum_{k_1\leq\cdots\leq k_n}p(m_1=k_1,\cdots,m_n=k_n)\mathbb{E}[f(X_{k_1},\cdots,X_{k_n})X_{k_n}|m_1=k_1,\cdots,m_n=k_n]
\end{align}
rather than the rhs of (2.5), unless the sampling variables (I believe they're also called stopping times) are uniformly distributed in the set of values satisfying the constraints.  Am I misunderstanding this, or is there a missing assumption here?

**EDIT** Following E-A, I get
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[f(\tilde{X}_1,\cdots,\tilde{X}_n)\tilde{X}_n]&=\sum_{k_1\leq,\cdots,\leq k_n}\int_{\omega:\{m_1=k_1,\cdots,m_n=k_n\}}f(\tilde{X}_1,\cdots,\tilde{X}_n)dP\\
&=\sum_{k_1\leq,\cdots,\leq k_n}\int_{\omega:\{m_1=k_1,\cdots,m_n=k_n\}}f(X_{k_1},\cdots,X_{k_n})dP\\
&=\sum_{k_1\leq\cdots\leq k_n} \mathbb{E}[f(X_{k_1},\cdots,X_{k_n})X_{k_n}|m_1=k_1,\cdots,m_n=k_n]
\end{align}
but I still don't know how that's equivalent to what I did earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What they did from (2.4) to (2.5) is to simply divide it up to different events. (It is essentially linearity of expectation; you are simply dividing up your domain)

What you did is also correct.

Comment: Can you help me understand how what I did and what they did are equivalent more clearly?

Comment: I added some details based on what I think your idea says.

Comment: the last equality is wrong; think of what conditional expectation is. Changing the domain itself is just multiplying by an indicator; conditional expectation is essentially renormalizing your domain.

Comment: I think I understand.  So the | indicates conditional expectation here, but the ; indicates integrating over a domain?

Comment: Yes, exactly indeed.